# how to get tax percentage in wp-ecommerce

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

I need to be able to get the tax percentage for the cart in wp-ecommerce.
I have tried using: $wpsc_cart->tax_percentage but it does not return a value.
Has something changed in the newer versions of wp-ecommerce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$wpsc_cart->tax_percentage` contains the tax percentage for me using the latest version 3.8.6. make sure you have enabled tax and added a tax rate under settings > store > taxes.

Comment: interesting I have enabled it and also added in a tax value but i get nothing. 
I have only pt in a  value and left it as all markets.
What globals are you using?